# Searching menu and returned ordered results

Tags: jquery, sorting, search

1. List item

I've got a menu system on my site that includes submenus.

I'm trying to add a search function that will allow my users to search across the entire menu and just show matching results. As they type the results are narrowed down until the required match is found.

I've got this working, but the results are not ordered alphabetically.
If I enter the character `h` I get :

```
Watch    
Hate    
Hates
```

If I then enter `a`, I get:

```
Hates    
Hate
```

I'd like the results to come back ordered `a to z`.

Does anyone know how to do this ?

```js
menu = $('#menu').html()

$("body").on('keyup', '#search', function(e) {
  searchfor = $(this).val()

  if (searchfor.length > 0) {
    $('#menu li').hide()

    $('.link').each(function(i, obj) {
      if (obj.text.search(new RegExp(searchfor, 'i')) > -1) {
        $('#menu').prepend($(this).closest('li').show())
      }
    })
  } else {
    $('#search').val('')
    $('#menu li').show()
    $('#menu').empty().append(menu)
  }

})
```

```css
@import "bourbon";
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,300,600);
body {
  font-family: "Lato";
  font-size: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  background-color: #fefefe;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  @include transition(all 0.6s ease);
  &:hover {
    @include transition(all 0.6s ease);
  }
}

.app {
  height: 100vh;
}


/* -------------
Sidebar
----------------*/

.sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  //width: 33.3333%;
  width: 17em;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #19222a;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  header {
    background-color: #09f;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    padding: 0.75em 1em;
  }
}


/* -------------
Sidebar Nav
----------------*/

.sidebar-nav {
  position: fixed;
  //width: 13em;
  background-color: #19222a;
  height: 100%;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  overflow: auto;
  padding-bottom: 6em;
  z-index: 9;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    li {
      margin-left: 0;
      padding-left: 0;
      //min-width: 13em;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 100%;
      a {
        color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
        font-size: 0.75em;
        padding: 1.05em 1em;
        position: relative;
        display: block;
        &:hover {
          background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
          @include transition(all 0.6s ease);
        }
      }
      /* -------------
Sidebar: icons
----------------*/
      i {
        font-size: 1.8em;
        padding-right: 0.5em;
        width: 9em;
        display: inline;
        vertical-align: middle;
      }
    }
  }
  /* -------------
Chev elements
----------------*/
  &>ul>li>a:after {
    content: '\f125';
    font-family: ionicons;
    font-size: 0.5em;
    width: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0.75em;
    top: 45%;
  }
  /* -------------
Nav-Flyout
----------------*/
  & .nav-flyout {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #080D11;
    z-index: 9;
    left: 2.5em;
    top: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    @include transform(translateX(100%));
    @include transition(all 0.5s ease);
    a:hover {
      background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05)
    }
  }
  /* -------------
Hover
----------------*/
  & ul>li:hover {
    .nav-flyout {
      @include transform(translateX(0));
      @include transition(all 0.5s ease);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="app">
  <aside class="sidebar">
    <nav class="sidebar-nav">
      <input type='text' id='search' value='' />
      <ul id='menu'>
        <li>
          <a href="#"><i class="ion-bag"></i> <span>Shop</span></a>
          <ul class="nav-flyout">
            <li>
              <a href="#" class='link' data-link='page1'><i class="ion-ios-color-filter-outline"></i>Derps</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class='link' data-link='page2'><i class="ion-ios-clock-outline"></i>Times</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class='link' data-link='page3'><i class="ion-android-star-outline"></i>Hates</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class='link' data-link='page4'><i class="ion-heart-broken"></i>Beat</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#"><i class="ion-ios-settings"></i> <span class="">Controls</span></a>
          <ul class="nav-flyout">
            <li>
              <a href="#" class='link' data-link='page5'><i class="ion-ios-alarm-outline"></i>Watch</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class='link' data-link='page6'><i class="ion-ios-camera-outline"></i>Creeper</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class='link' data-link='page7'><i class="ion-ios-chatboxes-outline"></i>Hate</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class='link' data-link='page8'><i class="ion-ios-cog-outline"></i>Grinder</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>

      </ul>
    </nav>
  </aside>
</section>
```

Comment: Put the returned values in an array, and use `array.sort()` to order them alphabetically.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] here, not at codepen. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: @Barmar the codepen link is showing as a code snippet and that has the same issue.

Comment: If I add the values to an array, the entries will be the `<li></li>` output, how do I sort that on the a `href text` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First filter the elements that match the search string. Then sort that list of elements before calling `.each()` to insert them into the output list.

```js
menu = $('#menu').html()

$("body").on('keyup', '#search', function(e) {
  let searchfor = $(this).val();

  if (searchfor.length > 0) {
    $('#menu li').hide();
    let regexp = new RegExp(searchfor, 'i');
    let filtered = $('.link').filter(function() {
      return regexp.test(this.innerText);
    });
    filtered.sort((l1, l2) => l2.innerText.localeCompare(l1.innerText))
      .each(function() {
        $('#menu').prepend($(this).closest('li').show())
      })
  } else {
    $('#search').val('')
    $('#menu li').show()
    $('#menu').empty().append(menu)
  }

})
```

```css
@import "bourbon";
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,300,600);
body {
  font-family: "Lato";
  font-size: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  background-color: #fefefe;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  @include transition(all 0.6s ease);
  &:hover {
    @include transition(all 0.6s ease);
  }
}

.app {
  height: 100vh;
}


/* -------------
Sidebar
----------------*/

.sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  //width: 33.3333%;
  width: 17em;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #19222a;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  header {
    background-color: #09f;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    padding: 0.75em 1em;
  }
}


/* -------------
Sidebar Nav
----------------*/

.sidebar-nav {
  position: fixed;
  //width: 13em;
  background-color: #19222a;
  height: 100%;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  overflow: auto;
  padding-bottom: 6em;
  z-index: 9;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    li {
      margin-left: 0;
      padding-left: 0;
      //min-width: 13em;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 100%;
      a {
        color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
        font-size: 0.75em;
        padding: 1.05em 1em;
        position: relative;
        display: block;
        &:hover {
          background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
          @include transition(all 0.6s ease);
        }
      }
      /* -------------
Sidebar: icons
----------------*/
      i {
        font-size: 1.8em;
        padding-right: 0.5em;
        width: 9em;
        display: inline;
        vertical-align: middle;
      }
    }
  }
  /* -------------
Chev elements
----------------*/
  &>ul>li>a:after {
    content: '\f125';
    font-family: ionicons;
    font-size: 0.5em;
    width: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0.75em;
    top: 45%;
  }
  /* -------------
Nav-Flyout
----------------*/
  & .nav-flyout {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #080D11;
    z-index: 9;
    left: 2.5em;
    top: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    @include transform(translateX(100%));
    @include transition(all 0.5s ease);
    a:hover {
      background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05)
    }
  }
  /* -------------
Hover
----------------*/
  & ul>li:hover {
    .nav-flyout {
      @include transform(translateX(0));
      @include transition(all 0.5s ease);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="app">
  <aside class="sidebar">
    <nav class="sidebar-nav">
      <input type='text' id='search' value='' />
      <ul id='menu'>
        <li>
          <a href="#"><i class="ion-bag"></i> <span>Shop</span></a>
          <ul class="nav-flyout">
            <li>
              <a href="#" class='link' data-link='page1'><i class="ion-ios-color-filter-outline"></i>Derps</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class='link' data-link='page2'><i class="ion-ios-clock-outline"></i>Times</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class='link' data-link='page3'><i class="ion-android-star-outline"></i>Hates</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class='link' data-link='page4'><i class="ion-heart-broken"></i>Beat</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#"><i class="ion-ios-settings"></i> <span class="">Controls</span></a>
          <ul class="nav-flyout">
            <li>
              <a href="#" class='link' data-link='page5'><i class="ion-ios-alarm-outline"></i>Watch</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class='link' data-link='page6'><i class="ion-ios-camera-outline"></i>Creeper</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class='link' data-link='page7'><i class="ion-ios-chatboxes-outline"></i>Hate</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class='link' data-link='page8'><i class="ion-ios-cog-outline"></i>Grinder</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>

      </ul>
    </nav>
  </aside>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2):

I hope this can help you: (based on your snippet)

```js
menu = $('#menu').html()

$("body").on( 'keyup', '#search', function(e) { 
        searchfor = $(this).val()

if ( searchfor.length > 0 ) {
  $('#menu li').hide()

  $('.link').each( function( i, obj ) {
      //console.log ( obj )
      if ( obj.text.search( new RegExp( searchfor, 'i') ) > -1 ) {
          $('#menu').prepend( $(this).closest('li').show() )

      }
  })
  //add this to sort result
  //===================================================
  //===================================================
  var sortedList=$("#menu li").sort(
    (e1,e2)=>{
      return $(e1).text().localeCompare($(e2).text())
    }
  );
  $('#menu li').detach();
  $('#menu').append(sortedList);
  //===================================================
  //===================================================
} else {
  $('#search').val('')      
  $('#menu li').show()
  $('#menu').empty().append( menu )
}
  
})
```

```css
@import "bourbon";
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,300,600);
body {
  font-family: "Lato";
  font-size: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  background-color: #fefefe;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  @include transition(all 0.6s ease);
  &:hover {
    @include transition(all 0.6s ease);
  }
}

.app {
  height: 100vh;
}


/* -------------
Sidebar
----------------*/

.sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  //width: 33.3333%;
  width: 17em;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #19222a;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  header {
    background-color: #09f;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    padding: 0.75em 1em;
  }
}


/* -------------
Sidebar Nav
----------------*/

.sidebar-nav {
  position: fixed;
  //width: 13em;
  background-color: #19222a;
  height: 100%;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  overflow: auto;
  padding-bottom: 6em;
  z-index: 9;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    li {
      margin-left: 0;
      padding-left: 0;
      //min-width: 13em;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 100%;
      a {
        color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
        font-size: 0.75em;
        padding: 1.05em 1em;
        position: relative;
        display: block;
        &:hover {
          background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
          @include transition(all 0.6s ease);
        }
      }
      /* -------------
Sidebar: icons
----------------*/
      i {
        font-size: 1.8em;
        padding-right: 0.5em;
        width: 9em;
        display: inline;
        vertical-align: middle;
      }
    }
  }
  /* -------------
Chev elements
----------------*/
  &>ul>li>a:after {
    content: '\f125';
    font-family: ionicons;
    font-size: 0.5em;
    width: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0.75em;
    top: 45%;
  }
  /* -------------
Nav-Flyout
----------------*/
  & .nav-flyout {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #080D11;
    z-index: 9;
    left: 2.5em;
    top: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    @include transform(translateX(100%));
    @include transition(all 0.5s ease);
    a:hover {
      background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05)
    }
  }
  /* -------------
Hover
----------------*/
  & ul>li:hover {
    .nav-flyout {
      @include transform(translateX(0));
      @include transition(all 0.5s ease);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="app">
  <aside class="sidebar">
    <nav class="sidebar-nav">
      <input type='text' id='search' value='' />
      <ul id='menu'>
        <li>
          <a href="#"><i class="ion-bag"></i> <span>Shop</span></a>
          <ul class="nav-flyout">
            <li>
              <a href="#" class='link' data-link='page1'><i class="ion-ios-color-filter-outline"></i>Derps</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class='link' data-link='page2'><i class="ion-ios-clock-outline"></i>Times</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class='link' data-link='page3'><i class="ion-android-star-outline"></i>Hates</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class='link' data-link='page4'><i class="ion-heart-broken"></i>Beat</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#"><i class="ion-ios-settings"></i> <span class="">Controls</span></a>
          <ul class="nav-flyout">
            <li>
              <a href="#" class='link' data-link='page5'><i class="ion-ios-alarm-outline"></i>Watch</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class='link' data-link='page6'><i class="ion-ios-camera-outline"></i>Creeper</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class='link' data-link='page7'><i class="ion-ios-chatboxes-outline"></i>Hate</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class='link' data-link='page8'><i class="ion-ios-cog-outline"></i>Grinder</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>

      </ul>
    </nav>
  </aside>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you return your results in an array you can use the array prototype sort() method to return them in order.

Comment: If I add the values to an array, the entries will be the `<li></li>` output, how do I sort that on the a `href text` ?

Comment: if you store the results in an array you will still be able to sort them as all elements of the array will have the <li></li> but the text inbetween will be different e.g <li>Watch</li>, <li>Hate</li> so when you sort it, it will still sort correctly.